Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at Object.inherits2 [as inherits] (@react-pdf_renderer.js?v=2aabb8bf:122:50)
    at ../../node_modules/blob-stream/index.js (@react-pdf_renderer.js?v=2aabb8bf:770:10)
    at __require2 (chunk-LK32TJAX.js?v=2aabb8bf:18:50)
    at ../../node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer/lib/react-pdf.cjs.js (@react-pdf_renderer.js?v=2aabb8bf:163313:22)
    at __require2 (chunk-LK32TJAX.js?v=2aabb8bf:18:50)
    at @react-pdf_renderer.js?v=2aabb8bf:163656:16

I tried to run and search to resolve the issue but getting the same error again and again.

Check if the @react-pdf/renderer and blob-stream libraries are up-to-date, as version mismatches often cause this error. Try importing blob-stream before @react-pdf/rerender to ensure proper loading. If the issue persists, clear your bundler's cache and restart the development server.

I have checked the version and these are the version for the specific dependencies "@react-pdf/render": "^2.1.0",
"blob-stream": "^0.1.3",

For me it's working, after updating react-pdf/renderer from ^2.1.0 to "@react-pdf/render": "3.4.4", .
